# Merge commits on diverging branches

Tags: git

This is best explained with an example:

```
git init
touch a # create the file "a"
git add a && git commit -m "a"
git checkout -b test # create and checkout the branch "test" 
touch t
git add t && git commit -m "t"
git checkout master
touch b 
git add b && git commit -m "b"
git checkout test 
git merge master # when I do the merge the editor pops up asking for a commit message with something like "merge with master" as the default, and this commit is the problem
```

Now here is the problem, i would expect the commit history of "test" to have three commits which are represented by their messages here(in the same order as `git log`):

> -- b
>   -- t
>   -- a

But instead I get:

> -- merge with master
>   -- t
>   -- b
>   -- a

The interesting thing is that both the [*b*] and [*merge with master*] commits have the same **diff** with their previous commit. And more interesting, is that <del>`HEAD^` actually points to ***[t]*** on "test"</del> `HEAD^^` points to ***[a]*** on "test".
I want to know why this happens and how I can avoid the [*merge with master*] commit. **Also, see Update-2.**
I should note that this won't happen if I don't do the [*t*] commit on branch "test", i.e: I will get two commits in its history after the merge: [*a*] and [*b*].

#### Update:

It seems like I can't use the `--ff-only` option and get the error "not possible to fast-forward". But why is that(since there are no conflicts)? This has been addressed in "ckruczek"'s comment.

#### Update-2:

I guess the question has shifted a little bit since its original posting:
The commits [*merge with master*] and [*b*] both have the *creation of "b"* inside them, so how is it that there are no errors when "playing these commits" in a sequence?

Comment: Does this help: https://ariya.io/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge

Comment: No, according to that, this should only happen by default when using github, but I'm doing it all manually.

Comment: There maybe is no conflict from your point of view, but for git, master and test have diverged and so git have to do a merge by default. You can overcome this issue by rebasing it locally like already suggested in the answer.

Comment: Also you can have git configured to never `fast-forward` with something like `git config --global merge.ff false`, so check your configuration as well

Comment: Re update 2, as a stack-overflow-specific meta-comment: don't try to change a question after it's already been answered; that just leads to confusion. Instead, post the question as a *new* question (after, of course, checking to see if there is already an answer elsewhere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Merge commits are *supposed to happen* on diverging branches**.

`gitk` provides a better visualization of commits than `git log` does.
When you merge two branches, then the order in which they appear in `git log` history is irrelevant; the important thing is that they're from two separate branches.

Here's a screenshot of gitk before you do a merge:

[image: Before Merge]

When you create the commit "t", then you create a *diverging branch* from master, which will proceed with the name *test*. If you're in the *test* branch, future commits will now be added on top of the commit "t".

Meanwhile, the *master* branch has another commit on top of "a", which is the commit "b". When you do a merge, what git does is that it condenses all commits of *test* into one and makes a commit on top of "b", which is known as a merge commit and has two parents - one from each branch. You can observe them in `gitk`.

Here's a screenshot after the merge:

[image: After Merge]

The commits "b" and "t" have nothing in common, so the merge commit gets created safely on top of "b", without any conflicts.

All that said, what you want is a linear history. If so, in the *test* branch, do a *rebase* instead of a merge:

```
$ git checkout test #making sure we're in 'test' branch
$ git rebase master
```

After the rebase, the history looks like this:

[image: Rebase]

The exact same thing; just that it's linear.

---

If you don't do the "t" commit, then the test branch points to the commit "a" and there's nothing in *test* that's not in *master*, so a *fast-forward merge* happens. That means that the *test* branch pointer is simply updated to point to the same commit as the newer *master* branch.

**In response to the latest comment by OP**

What you've done in your code is checked out *test* and merged *master* into it, which is typically the opposite of when you'd do a merge in practice, since the *master* branch is the main one. In that case, I'd do:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge test
```

which looks like this:

[image: Actual Merge]

Here, the *master* branch is now pointing to the merge commit, and the merge commit contains "b" in it.

If you want to revert this commit, then doing something like:

```
$ git revert <merge commit id>
```

won't work - since the merge is between two branches. You'll have to specify a parent number to go with the merge. To revert changes in "b", you'll have to say "I want to revert the main master branch", like:

```
$ git revert -m 1 <merge commit id>
```

which will revert the commit "b". Specifying 2 would've reverted the test branch, and commit "t".

Comment: Be careful when rebasing, though. Rebasing recreates the commits, i.e. the commits are the same but their hash values change. Never rebase the upstream branch, as it'll cause problems in others' repositories. Only rebase locally *before* you push.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually run into that problem with rebase.

Comment: But you still haven't addressed what's said in update-2. The thing is I'm wondering what happens when a merged commit, e.g: "b" gets reverted, because it (at least looks like) it's duplicated in both the "b" commit and the "merge" commit.

Comment: "b" is not there in the merge commit. The merge commit contains all contents of the *test* branch, whereas the "b" commit comes before the merge commit in the *master* branch. The merge commit is simply a combination of all commits in the `test` branch. If I decide I don't want the merge commit anymore, I'd just do a hard reset to the "t" commit and start over.

Comment: Accepted. The concept would have been the same on the "test" branch though.

Comment: @user2268997 For git, yes. But it's always expected that you'd merge the new branch into the old, not the other way round. So you'd checkout to the old(master) and merge the new one in. In case of rebase, you'd checkout to the new branch, since rebase effectively means "take all new commits from here and superimpose on old branch".

Answer (score 1):

This is how the graph looks like before the `git merge` command:

```
  * 355aaea b             <-------- master is here
* | 4bfc6f1 t             <-------- test is here
|/  
* fd7cb2e a
```

As you can see, your commands created the branch `test` that diverged from `master`.

This is what `git log --graph` shows after `git merge`:

```
$ git log --graph
*   be820db Merge branch 'master' into test
|\  
| * 355aaea b
* | 4bfc6f1 t
|/  
* fd7cb2e a
```

The branch `master` still points to `355aaea` (the merge affects only the current branch), `test` moved to the new commit (`be820db`).

Merging divergent branches requires the creation of a new commit (`be820db`) that has two parents: `4bfc6f1` (currently pointed at by `t`) and `355aaea` (currently pointed at by `master`). `4bfc6f1` is the first parent because `test` was the current branch when the `git merge` command was issues. The other parents are the branches specified in the `git merge` command, in the order they are specified in the command line.

Fast-forwarding is possible only when the current branch is an ancestor of the merge you want to branch. For example, given the current status of the repository, the following commands produce a "fast-forward" merge:

```
$ git branch new fd7cb2e
$ git checkout new
$ git merge test
```

The "fast-forward" merge is possible because the merged branch (`test`) contains commits that are not in the current branch (`new`) but the current branch does not contains commits that are not in the merged branch. In this situation, a new commit is not required because it doesn't produce anything new. The "fast-forward" means the current branch is moved forward until it reaches the merged commit.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?